# Where to trigger ast modifications in Python?

Tags: python

I'm doing some AST modifications in Python. This may be done for optimization purpose or other.

Where is the right place to put it, so when you do something like:

```
python myfile.py
```

or

```
python runserver.py myapp
```

the modifications took place for every .py executed file?

Answer (score 0):

Put your modifications in a `site.py` or `sitecustomize.py` (Python < 2.6) file (in the `lib/site-packages` directory ; Python will try [to import and run](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) it @ interpreter startup).

Comment: But how do I access to-be-executed python files from there?